# Complete beginner advice on 74HC decoupling on PCB

Tags: pcb

I just started PCB design today (using KiCad) so I don't have to deal with a mess of jumpers for a homemade 74xx CPU on a breadboard. In addition to what value and type of decoupling capacitors I should use, I'd like to know how to route them (how far from the chip, how much to place some chips, specific trace width/turns/via requirements, etc.)

Comment: Have you seen [Decoupling capacitors for 7400 type chips](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353567/decoupling-capacitors-for-7400-type-chips)?

Comment: if you're a complete beginner, first start by looking at existing designs. Luckily there's over 50 years worth of examples for 74xx series.

Answer (score 2):

I hope and I wish that you have a great time in Kicad.

Don't worry too much about the particular capacitance - something like 10 nF to 100 nF sounds about right. One capacitor per IC package. As I generally try to have large areas of GND even on double-sided boards (i.e. just two layers) I generally put those caps close to the Vcc pin of each IC, and run a via to the "ground plane". I also place the parts such that they don't prevent me from soldering the IC's and capacitors = no problem if you add an extra mm or two. Or, I can place the caps on the underside (solder side) and the via goes to the Vcc pin.

Andrew Morton has linked to a nice topic where this is debated in more detail. If you're interested in further reading, google [Murata C39E application note](https://www.google.com/search?q=Murata%20C39E%20application%20note). Note that apart from capacitance, capacitors in the debated range feature a parasitic resonance that is relevant at the switching speeds of those devices - so a larger MLCC is not always better. And if you're into *fast* circuitry, you may want be aware of the [anti-resonance phenomenon](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320363/antiresonance-of-multiple-parallel-decoupling-capacitors-use-same-value-or-mult) when combining multiple capacitors. See also the [Kemet KSIM](https://ksim3.kemet.com/) tool. But I'm probably fetching this a little too far already :-)

With many logic or mixed-signal chips, you typically find a recommended style of power blocking in the datasheet or in an application note (often with an example PCB layout). Not so with the generic 74xx family - I know.